Python RSA Encryption - Using Private Key to Encrypt and Public to Decrypt
I am working on creating a license key validation server that unlocks a piece of software. The C++ framework I am using, for the client, has built in functionality that allows the server to send back a POST response with an RSA encrypted message containing data that states the license key is valid for the machine sending the POST.
The way the framework handles response encryption is by housing the public key in the client software and the private key on the server doing a reverse version of typical RSA encryption. I understand that this is not necessarily secure but for this use case it does not matter. I have also read that this may be called signing rather than encrypting but I am unsure.
I am writing the server in python and am therefore wanting to do reverse RSA encyption using python libraries.
I have tried a couple different things, mainly using the pycryptodome library but have been unable to get a successful run. Below I have an encrypt and decrypt function I found but it throws an incorrect padding error when attempting to use b64decode. I tried researching how to fix the padding but was unsuccesful.
I have provided sample private and public keys, as well as a testMsg that the framework spit out when encrypting with the private key.
from http.server import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import time
import sqlite3
from random import choice
from string import ascii_uppercase, digits
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA
from Crypto.Cipher import PKCS1_OAEP
import base64


hostName = "localhost"
serverPort = 8080
serverVersion = "v0.2.3"
privateRSAKey = "279808e40cef4350640026c8739e7201826d002cec7e260f3d16d0cf786842f1,602815978d207ee7ce4982c23d5c39729da90af57b850863165936256e3b7227"
publick = "11,602815978d207ee7ce4982c23d5c39729da90af57b850863165936256e3b7227"
testMsg = "#62a29db7f09c76d2b28a2313911cbaad1a89b235ab52d05f704a9110c517b1db90d824d88188d08cb2b9002ba2f64e0bdf78a393a7cfc3f2bbad0e43f8167184975183357c2a73e1537fb0fe47e74586d553bc68e0e4e03d6b1ef67d03e57ea794f0029db1d6b2ef048db4e6b019d198e2876e925dc3036bbcca85369f67435884a9ff60a28a3e6131056805b58f804e74a8a224453b5099f831c57a16f87e"

def encrypt_private_key(a_message, private_key):
    encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(private_key)
    encrypted_msg = encryptor.encrypt(a_message)
    print(encrypted_msg)
    encoded_encrypted_msg = base64.b64encode(encrypted_msg)
    print(encoded_encrypted_msg)
    return encoded_encrypted_msg

def decrypt_public_key(encoded_encrypted_msg, public_key):
    encryptor = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
    decoded_encrypted_msg = base64.b64decode(encoded_encrypted_msg)
    print(decoded_encrypted_msg)
    decoded_decrypted_msg = encryptor.decrypt(decoded_encrypted_msg)
    print(decoded_decrypted_msg)

def verify_product(product):
    if product == "Test":
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def verify_email(email):
    if email == "test@email.com":
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
def verify_license_key(licenseKey):
    sql_connection = sqlite3.connect("SynergyLicenseKey.db");
    cur = sql_connection.cursor()

    data = cur.execute(f"SELECT * FROM LICENSEKEYS WHERE LicenseKey = '{licenseKey}'")

    # if rows return it is a valid license key
    for row in data:
        sql_connection.close()
        return True

    sql_connection.close()
    return False
    
    
def generate_license_key():
    # Using random.choice to select characters from uppercase letters and digits
    key = ''.join([choice(ascii_uppercase + digits) for _ in range(7)]) + '-' + \
          ''.join([choice(ascii_uppercase + digits) for _ in range(7)]) + '-' + \
          ''.join([choice(ascii_uppercase + digits) for _ in range(7)])
    
    return key

class testServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        
    def do_POST(self):
        content_length = int(self.headers['Content-Length'])
        post_data = self.rfile.read(content_length)
        request_data = post_data.decode('utf-8').split('&')
        print(request_data)

        if verify_product(request_data[0][8:]) and verify_email(request_data[1][6:]):
            response = bytes(f'<MESSAGE message="Success! Valid License Key"><KEY>{test}</KEY></MESSAGE>', "utf-8")
        else:
            response = bytes('<ERROR error="Invalid License Key"></ERROR>', "utf-8")
        
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-Length", str(len(response)))
        self.end_headers()
        
        self.wfile.write(response)
        
    
        

if __name__ == "__main__":        
    webServer = HTTPServer((hostName, serverPort), testServer)
    print("Server - " + serverVersion + " - http://%s:%s" % (hostName, serverPort))
    decrypt_public_key(testMsg, publick)
    try:
        webServer.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    webServer.server_close()
    print("Server stopped.")



Yes it is insecure, and yes it is called digital signing. If verification via digital signature  is not your purpose do not do this, and in any case please don’t describe it as encryption. It isn’t.

Note that an RSA public key is always considered public knowledge even if it isn't explicitly shared. See for instance here where the modulus can be calculated given a few signatures (i.e. calculations performed with the private key) as long as the message is known or can be guessed. You can use signatures or even the old signatures giving message recovery (with questionable security) but those do not offer confidentiality of the information within the signature for obvious reasons.
